# I'm new to magento I'm adding new products in homepage it display 3 products in a row I want to display more than 3 product in a row

Tags: magento-1.9.3.3

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
<action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>6</columns></action>
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>6</count></action> 
</block>
</reference>
```

Below is how I am trying to call via cms:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="5" column_count="4"" product_count="9" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```